# Is it possible to check the 'git status' of all the files processed by grunt?

Tags: git, gruntjs

Let's suppose I have a project with several files (e.g `.html`, `.js`, `.css`, `.cs` etc). The files are released with `grunt`, which creates a `build/` folder from my input `src/` files.

During this process, it doesn't include all of my `src` files, and it also changes the names of some files (to `.min.js` and `.min.css` for example).
The list of the input files are specified in the tasks with `src` parameter and the renaming is done with the `ext` parameter.
This is cool, every information about the files to be included in the release are in the `grunt` file.

But is it possible to check automatically that if input files are also added to git?

It would be very frustrating making hundreds of releases for months and later figuring out that I forgot to add an important file to git right at the first release.
This would mean that all the previous `snapshots` stored in `git` are incomplete.

I know that some automated `Jenkins` tests could help, but these tests should probably contain another, independently created file list. It would be a good second check, but the situations would not be easier.

Grunt knows everything about the source files which are needed for the release and can do many checks during the release.
It would be nice if grunt could do a `git status` before running their tasks and it could apply a `source filter` before applying a task to check the presence of the files in git.

Creating a grunt task, or executing a git command line would be also be a solution, but I'm afraid I would need to list all my `src` lists and `ext` parameters again for this solution.

Note: For the development, I'm using Windows and Linux, too.

Comment: Isn't your `.gitignore` file sufficient? When you are doing your release if you are using `git commit -a`, it will add all your files for sure (unless specified in `.gitignore`). So the question is what is your release process, because your release process will definitely add all your files. `*.min.css` and `*.min.js` are usually considered artifacts and are not versioned with git with the same repo (but this is not a convention followed by the most web developers, but is the convention used by most Java/C/Go developers)

Comment: azbarcea: Yes, this is also a possible solution. Although it has some drawbacks:

- Gruntfile.js and .gitignore has to have exactly the same filters. So manual synchronization is necessary.

- I usually use `.gitignore` as a pre-filter. E.g if I have several development versions of a file (e.g. `js/util-bad.js`, `js/util-objectcopy_test.js`) then I don't always update it.

But .gitignore could be only a good indicator if it normally contains 0 untracked files, otherwise you will not easily notice that now it has 13 untracked files instead of 12.

Comment: azbarcea: As a summary: `.gitignore` works only if the developer's working copy is clean and tidy. But what if not? If the he/she has a little mess in their files? -
Grunt can notify about **almost all** easy errors. If the developer wants to have all the source files to be version controlled then it would be also an easy check.
As a workaround it would be enough if grunt could list all the source files which were processed.

Comment: Based on my previous idea, I've found a workaround.
Fortunately `grunt -v` prints the necessary output. So now I'm adding the code as an answer to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a script, which does everything important for me.
However, I'm not a big Windows script expert so I had to split it into two parts.

The first line has to be executed in PowerShell and the others can be started from a standard cmd window.

```
REM PowerShell:
REM grunt -v | findstr /R '^Reading' | %{$_ -replace '^Reading','@git status -s'} | %{$_ -replace '...OK$',''} | Out-File git_check.bat ASCII

git_check.bat
del git_check.bat
```

An example output of the temporal batch script, git_check.bat:

```
w:\Project>git_check.bat
?? src/js/output_SUSPEND.js
?? src/js/3rdparty/lz-string.js
?? src/img/ajax-loader.gif
```

Anybody with an easier, one-script solution?